# Commercial website build from scratch or use some template?

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to build a company to demonstrate and sell our products. It should be a catalog of products that can be edited. Each item should have a picture, description, price and people can make orders.

I can develop the catalog in Ruby on Rails or Asp.net MVC, but I have yet to get familiar with online payment tools. Are there any security issues I need to consider?

Since this site is basically a CMS site, I am also wondering if there is any free CMS template I can use, too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be handling the actual sale of products (I.E., handling credit cards), there are MANY security issues you need to consider - the most significant being the requirements of the Payment Card Industry (PCI) Data Security Standard (DSS).

Unless you're looking to make at least full-time operation out of this, I'd strongly recommend using a hosted solution - even something like an Amazon or an eBay store, both of which should meet your requirements around a picture, description, price, and handling of orders.